# How to know if an URL matches specific PATH

Tags: java, url, path

I am trying to execute some logic in a Java filter depending if request URL matches a specific PATH. We want to use something like Java's PathMatcher and no Regex. Additionally requirement, explicitly states no to use Spring so spring's PathMatcher is not an option.

> For instance given following URL:
>    http://localhost:8080/base_path/customer/{PARAM_VAL1}/order/{PARAM_VAL2}

I'm looking someway to cause IF to yield true:

```
PathMatcher pm = new SomeURLPathMatcherImp("/base_path/customer/*/order/*");

myURI = "/base_path/customer/customer001/order/98536"

if ( pm. matches(myURI) ){
    myFunction();
}
```

NOTE: I used PathMatcher to depict the issue. I want to know is there is any API lib other than Spring to perform URL PATH matching similar to Java's FileSystem class implementation

Comment: What is your question? How to obtain a `PathMatcher`? Since it's an interface, you can't use `new`, but if you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`PathMatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html), you will see a reference to [`FileSystem.getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-) in the "See Also" section. And if you read the javadoc of that, you'll learn how it works.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for you comment. 
Every stackoverflow user should exhaust all posibilities before posting the question. And one is to read the documentation. 
Back to my question, 
To achiefve what I need, I would not expect to use FileSystem class in a Java Web Filter to test URLs. Or Is it the right thing to do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
PathMatcher pm = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:/base_path/customer/*/order/*");

System.out.println(pm.matches(Paths.get("/base_path/customer/customer001/order/98536")));  // true
System.out.println(pm.matches(Paths.get("/base_path/customer/customer001/order")));        // false
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692080/url-path-matcher-in-java-spring solved my problem